# Swift: URLSession extension configuration error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'URLSession'

Tags: swift, combine, urlsession, xcode14, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I have this function:

```
class myClass: ObservableObject {
    
    func doSomethingElse<T:Decodable>(url: URL,
                                      config: URLSessionConfiguration,
                                      type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<Int, any Error> {
        return URLSession(configuration:config).dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap{ response in
                guard let valueResponse = response.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    return 000
                }
                return valueResponse.statusCode
            }.mapError{error in
                return error
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

and it works just fine but I'm trying to add this function to `URLSession` extension:

```
extension URLSession {
    
    func doSomethingElse<T:Decodable>(url: URL,
                                      config: URLSessionConfiguration,
                                      type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<Int, any Error> {
       return self(configuration:config).dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap{ response in
                guard let valueResponse = response.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    return 000
                }
                return valueResponse.statusCode
            }.mapError{error in
                return error
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'URLSession'
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or how can configure URLSession to have the configuration?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is the specific instance of `URLSession`. You want `Self`, which is the *type*

```
Self(configuration:config)...
```

You may also want `doSomethingElse` to be a `static` function, since it doesn't actually reference the specific instance of `self`:

```
static func doSomethingElse<T:Decodable>(url: URL,
                                      config: URLSessionConfiguration,
                                      type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<Int, any Error> {
        return Self(configuration:config).dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap{ response in
                guard let valueResponse = response.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    return 000
                }
                return valueResponse.statusCode
            }.mapError{error in
                return error
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
func doSomethingElse...{
   return self(configuration:...
```

To

```
static func doSomethingElse...{
   return Self(configuration:...
```

Call it as

```
URLSession.doSomethingElse...
```